# Grant fraud, should I bust my PhD advisor?

Tags: phd, advisor, funding, research-misconduct, whistleblowing

**tl;dr:** Should I report this large grant fraud, and what consequences could it have for me?

For obvious reasons, I will try to maintain some anonymity here.

So I defended my thesis. Which was funded through a government grant.

In order to obtain this type of grant, a professor needs to cooperate with several other research organizations and privately-owned industries. Then it is required for some people to exchange between these places for extended periods of time. Relocate to a different place, live and work there.

So my industrious professor submitted all the required paperwork and received enough money to support multiple PhD students, post-docs and senior professors. However, almost none of them actually did any exchange. Instead, everyone just stayed at their home institutions.

Of course, I had no idea that the grant money was being mishandled until a monitoring meeting with the grant authorities that took place a long time after I started. All the other PhD students had no idea what was going on as well. We ended up making ridiculous statements about our accommodation, work hours, health insurance as the senior professors convinced us to lie about fictitious exchanges taking place.

The whole scheme is based on deliberate misinformation about people working at places they have never seen in their lives. I suspect a ton of papers and documents had been forged and submitted as evidence. The government thinks it's a research project with cooperation among multiple institutions. The only time we see each other is at set-up (pretended) conferences.

Naturally, all the documentation is kept secret, but a quick Google search would reveal that one can't simultaneously work at place *x*, and give lectures at place *y*, while *x* and *y* are hours of travel away. But again the people who control the grant money only check the paperwork they are provided. Is there a bogus employment contract in my name? I don't know but I have reasons to believe so.

Should I report this as a fraud?

There is an anti-fraud unit which should deal with it. This could, however, backfire in so many unimaginable ways. Forgery is rather a serious offense: a few PhD students and post-docs could end up being deported. More money is being awarded each year which could go to other researchers that are at least honest about what they spend it on. A funded PhD position is still available at my university, so more unsuspecting students will be involved.

I don't even know how I should approach this problem myself. It is an ethical dilemma as to whether I should support my supervisors. The procedure is definitely illegal, but the consequences could vary from not receiving future funding from the same source, to grant recovery (many millions of an unspecified currency) or even criminal charges. I can only speculate on what documents have been forged in the process, employment contracts, visa documents etc. A large number of involved researchers don't even live on the same continent, and that is where most of the money might go to. It is also very personal. Apart from being fooled with many false promises into writing a PhD, I did not sign up for, nor intended to, lie about living in a place I have never been to.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for, since nobody can make the decision for you ("Should I?"). Can you [edit] your post to clarify your question? For example, are you asking if you have an ethical responsibility to report? What the consequences of reporting are likely to be? Something else?

Comment: Should I is something you can answer, How can I, is something people might be able to guide you on.  Probably the funding agency has an email address, if you are really adamant about telling them.

Comment: So you were convinced to lie to government officials in order to complete a PhD which you regard as being intellectually worthless and left you struggling to find an entry-level job?  What a sad story.

Comment: Yes It is a sad story, just like many PhDs are. In fact there are other students on the same wagon.

Comment: Be the change you want to see in the world. If you don't speak out about it, these practices will simply continue until someone else is brave enough to do something about it. Sure, it's risky business for you, but it will always be for whoever thinks about doing it. If you don't speak out, essentially you're a co-conspirator.

Comment: I don't want to burn all the bridges. Having given how low reputation my department already has, if it looses the primary source of income the university could close it down.

Comment: Since it seems that you yourself may have contributed to the fraud by lying to the grant authorities, I would think you really ought to consult a lawyer.  It sounds like there are lots of people who know about this, and if one of them decides to blow the whistle before you do, you could have some serious problems.

Comment: You do understand that if the grant is revoked, you will have to return all the  money you received from this grant (as everyone else). Then you will see if you are still loan-free to repay all that. Also, you will have to face the same law  consequences, since you also lied, provided false written documents and conspired to the fraud as everyone. Strong ethics do not come for free

Comment: "We ended up making ridiculous statements about our accommodation..." and whose idea was that?  Did your supervisor directly say 'you need to lie about what you have been doing because I am stealing money from these people'?  As Nate and Alexandros point out, there are some other issues you may have to deal with, and some people playing dumb to what students said or thought were lies might not be good for you.

Comment: You need to consult a lawyer. As @Alexandros pointed out - you will very likely be considered a part of the fraud. Apart from having to return the money you may also face criminal charges - in my country, getting over a few hundred $ illegally brings you automatically to court. You may want to check your country's whistleblower/cooperating defendant protection laws, but those (if existent) usually do not provide any strict protection - court will have to decide whether you will face charges. OTOH, if the scheme is revealed, you will be in much worse situation than if you had spoken.

Comment: @rantingPhDstudent: "I don't want to burn all the bridges." - Fully understandable why you would want to avoid that. "(...) if [the department] looses the primary source of income the university could close it down." - Actually, not quite understandable why you would specifically want to avoid this outcome. The ethical issues mentioned by others left aside, it is clear you would want to reduce the possible fallout, but by explicitly stating that the department could be closed down to be the issue, it sounds like you feel an inherent legitimacy to the department's existence, as well as ...

Comment: ... some kind of a personal attachment (it's "your" department, "you" must not harm it). If this is actually the case, I suggest you reconsider this "team spirit" mentality. You are responsible for your decisions, not your department. Conversely, "rescuing" your department cannot absolve you from unwise decisions that you might make to achieve that goal.

Comment: I removed some (imho unnecessary) parts of your question, feel free to restore the original question if you disagree.

Comment: Some of these comments and answers seem unrealistically pessimistic to me. Yes, this sounds like a big grant fraud. Yes, shit is likely going to hit the fan at some point. Yes, both the department and the advisor (as well as the other senior professors) are likely in trouble then. No, the probability that the OP will have to pay back money is very, very small. No, even if this becomes a legal fraud case, I would very much doubt that any serious charges are raised *against the PhD students* (unless the department somehow manages to throw them under the bus, which is not very realistic).

Comment: Let me put it differently: when a fraudulent company gets busted, the people that get charged are the ones that sign the contracts and/or who have a formal responsibility (e.g., the official financial controller). Nobody raises charges against the interns and entry-level staff, even though the probably also knew about (parts of) the machinations. That being said, getting a lawyer is still probably a good idea.

Comment: @xLeitix I agree that the responsibility might in the end not be with the OP, but the case is different from the company fraud scenario as it can easily be argued that OP had personal profit from the fraud. Also in fraudulent companies, the employees typically claim to have acted in good faith or under threats. The difference is subtle and in the end the decision will probably lie with court (if there is any). And these subtleties are exactly why you need a professional lawyer.

Comment: which country/jurisdiction are you in?

Comment: My advice- to Ph.D. students, generally- is to build or find a time machine, go back before you started the Ph.D. program, and then... don't. So far, that strategy has a 100% success rate.

Comment: While not as severe as your case I omitted a year of university when I transferred into the college I graduated from. I reported the omission about a year in and was called in front of a disciplinary committee. They actually respected that I tried to remedy my mistake and let me off with a warning. I am very happy I came forward and can't imagine still having that inconsistency on my record. It will greatly benefit you morally and professionally to come forward. These things can, and have, come back to haunt people many years down the road.

Comment: @MartinČerný I agree with xLeitix. Just like in fraudulent companies the OP could claim good faith (advisor: this is how its done in academia) or threat, too (advisor: do it or I'll fire you and make sure you never land a position in my field of academia). Statements implying that "we used a questionable accounting trick to be able to buy a new device we really needed for research" is ok-ish, make good faith all the more plausible. And if the presumably well connected advisor gets out of this, blacking his name to all his colleagues is a very real threat too, if OP wants to stay in academia.

Comment: This should be in the next weekend reads on Retractionwatch.

Comment: I would guess that in most European countries it is unlikely that the OP has to personally pay back any money. It is more likely that his/her PhD title is revoked, as it was granted as part of a fraudulent scheme.

Comment: @DannyRuijters: I am not sure why the revocation of the PhD title is so frequently brought up here. The major part of the described scheme seems to be about manipulating the *organisational* framework. While the scientific results are not necessarily of a very high quality, the one misdeed that is *not* implied to have happened here is the manipulation or faking of scientific results. As such, it would seem rather odd to acknowledge that the OP wilfully helped cover up the funding fraud for a while and not act on it, but instead deny the scientific merit the work might still have after all.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I personally don't want to revoke anybody's title. I have noticed, however, that in academic fraud investigations often the question is raised whether any degrees have been granted without being deserved. Since in most European countries the PhD student is not the direct recipient of the grant, it is unlikely that the OP would need to pay anything back in Europe.

Comment: "if one of them decides to blow the whistle before you do, you could have some serious problems"
This seems like a classical Prisoner's dilemma.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoners_dilemma

Comment: @rantingPhDstudent want a really good advice? DO NOT POST about your own CRIMES on the web. To delete this question right now (I think its already to late) is your best bet. Good luck in jail.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Now we are already talking about jail time :) ? You guys have a vivid phantasy.

Comment: @xLeitix From the question, it sounds like the OP might have personally lied to government grant officers. While it was under the direction of professors, that goes beyond just knowing about fraud and not saying anything; I don't know what country the OP is in, but in the US they could well be facing charges if they personally lied to government grant officials.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think that the OP's concern for the department has less to do with bringing down those responsible for this, but for all of the other Graduate Students who are not a party to this and will lose years of time and work if the Department is shuttered. One only needs to look at some of the financial scandals of the past 25 years to see the knock on ramifications for the misdeeds of the few.

Comment: You should most certainly report them - it is ethically, morally, and professionally correct.  Remember that if this effects your professional or personal life in any way you will be able to sue the university, its board, the professors involved and possibly even the government.  Personally speaking, I would see you as an honest person - the kind of person I think companies will want.

Comment: You are creating a false dichotomy: get your damn PhD awarded first *and* start your new job before you contemplate doing any of this. It's near-impossible to retract a PhD after it's been awarded, but it's very easy to retaliate against a candidate beforehand. Get your priorities straight. The fraud will likely be discovered someday, even if you don't intervene. Do not be consumed by having been fooled by false promises, it happens to many of us, and guess what? industry is just like that, except presumably more zeros after the numbers.

Comment: In the US, see ... [Honest Services Fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honest_services_fraud#Meaning_of_%22honest_services%22_in_private_fiduciary_relationships) and the [The full indictment charging actors, CEOs and others in a nationwide college admission scheme](https://www.cnn.com/2019/03/12/us/indictment-college-admissions-scheme/index.html).

Answer (score 164):

TLDR: You need a lawyer.

---

I think, ethically, speaking out is the right thing. Falsifying grants is despicable and has a very negative impact on science in general. It has happened to me multiple times that when I say in a pub that I am in science and that I got a grant people say things like "All those grants are just frauds to get money from the government/EU". I don't think I need to explain why this kind of perception hurts on both personal and systemic level.

Regarding your own well being, things are much more difficult. The fact is that you have **willingly** participated in a non-trivial fraud for a **prolonged** period of time. Speaking out will not erase this neither ethically nor legally.

You need to consult a **lawyer** (not an Internet law advice, a real lawyer). As pointed out in the comments - you may easily be considered a part of the fraud. You may want to check your country's whistleblower/cooperating defendant protection laws, but those (if existent) usually do not provide any strict protection - court will have to decide whether you will face charges. OTOH, if the scheme is revealed later without your involvement, you will be in much worse situation than if you had spoken.
You may also claim to have acted in good faith or under serious threat (losing employment). Once again, a lawyer should be able to tell you to what extent this may protect you under the relevant jurisdiction, *given the specific circumstances* (there is no simple general rule).

Be aware, that you are in trouble. I don't think there are so many grants of this kind and much fewer of them are being cheated like the one you speak about. There is a non-negligible chance that someone overseeing the project reads this post and may consider checking whether this isn't "his" project. Some other participant of the grant may read this as well and consider speaking out himself to get into a better situation. And as this sounds like a big and ongoing fraud, it may easily burst on its own - once people get too much used to bending rules they usually do not know when to stop.

This is not a "we used a questionable accounting trick to be able to buy a new device we really needed for research" kind of problem, there is no good intent, neither was the money used in the spirit of the grant.

**EDIT:** One more bad scenario in response to some of the comments. Let's suppose the fraud is exposed. Even if the funding agency does not initiate a criminal investigation and even if they cannot directly claim money from you (as your contract is probably with the uni) you still have trouble. Since the uni will likely have to return a large sum of money, they can file civil suit against the people involved in the fraud seeking financial compensation for the loss. As you have made false statements about accommodation and other stuff, this can easily include you.

**EDIT 2:** I would like to highlight a good point made in [AndrejaKo's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/51346/26495): If the corruption is sufficiently deep in the system, it might not be actually possible to bust your advisor (read [the answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/51346/26495) for detailed reasoning).

Comment: An important thing to add to this answer, I think, is that if you decide not to report the fraudulent activity now but that it somehow does get discovered in the future the consequences for you could end up being even more negative than they are now.  Sorry to add more complexity to the consideration.

Comment: How did you get "willingly"? As I understand the OP, he has only learned of the misuse "a long time after he started": *"Of course I had no idea that the grant money is being mishandled"*. I don't really think that the OP is in any very concrete danger of being tagged as an accessory to this fraud.

Comment: @xLeitix Once you make a statement which you now is false, to gain something (continued grant funding in this case) you are willingly commiting fraud, unless you prove you had no other option - which does not seem to be the case. It would be hard to argue (legally) that being forced to quit a PhD is such a dire consequence. I am referring to this part: "We ended up making ridiculous statements about our accommodation, work hours, health insurance"

Comment: @MartinČerný. To add to your arguments, the OP could resign anytime from the grant without leaving his PhD. The PhD is between him and the host institution and he could just continue without receiving funding.

Comment: _This is not a "we used a questionable accounting trick to be able to buy a new device we really needed for research" kind of problem, there is no good intent, neither was the money used in the spirit of the grant._
Do we know this? Maybe the research was actually being done, just without people moving around. It's certainly safer for the OP to report, but I don't know that we have enough information to say if it's ethically necessary.

Comment: @rantingPhDstudent I agree with the suggestion to consult legal counsel.  In addition, on your own, I'd suggest carefully establishing a timeline: when you joined the project, when you suspected fraud, when you confirmed it, when you communicated with the grant monitor, etc. Collect any and all documentation that you have that pertains to you and the grant and keep a copy for yourself; if the evidence is "lost", it's your word against theirs. You may want to review your uni's policies/structure to see if there is a Vice-Chancellor of Res. / Provost who would rep the uni in this matter, IMHO.

Comment: @Alexandros We still don't know EU or US, but from my German POV continuing the PhD without the advisor or the funding is unrealistic. PhDs are usually bound to their advisor from day one and switching to a different advisor usually means starting over. College loans aren't as established here, especially not for PhD. Moreover, his visa might depend on having a job (PhD counts as a job because it usually is). So yes he could resign any time but what might that mean for him? He might be able to plead that he had a relationship of dependence on the advisor, which might get him a lighter charge.

Comment: @xLeitix in many jurisdictions lying to an auditor is, by itself, a crime. There is no doubt that the OP did that. That was the moment when they became implicated in the fraud. (And saying "i'd lose my PhD if I didn't participate" probably does not come close to meeting the legal standard of "forced to participate").

Comment: Here is one thing that doesn't quite make sense. As far as I have seen, grant money generally doesn't go directly to the researcher that has applied for it. It usually goes into a research trust that the University controls and payout only occurs when proper documentation is produced. So signed timesheets, plane tickets, expense reports with receipts, purchase orders, leases if you are living in funded housing have to be provided before a reimbursement is made. It usually isn't a PI being handed a bag of cash. Where is the oversight at the institutional level at this university?

Answer (score 71):

Since the question is intentionally vague, I think there's one more angle that should be considered in the general case and that everyone missed: Can I actually bust my PhD adviser?

Let's be honest: Such deep level of cover-ups shows that entire operation is being conducted in a society that allows corruption, so it would be a bit naive to think it's only localized to academia.

Assuming you actually have sufficient evidence to incriminate the whole gang, can you be sure that someone is going to act on those evidence?   Are you sure that none of the implicated professors have a colleague from law school who just happens to be best friends with the prosecutor to whom your case gets assigned to? Or the judge? Can you be 100% sure that your case won't spend next XX years untouched at the bottom of the stack of the cases that need to be solved?

If the behavior you're describing is being tolerated by such large number of people, can you be 100% sure that there's absolutely no government backing in it? Are you sure that people controlling the grant money are as incompetent/naive as they look and are not in fact somehow taking a percentage of the grant money for themselves? We'll give you 100 million, but you'll give me 1 million!

To put is simply, I suspect that there could be a very serious danger that you could report this to the authorities, exposing yourself in that way and burning all bridges with your research community, and at the same time have authorities do absolutely nothing about it, other than perhaps prosecuting you personally for your contribution to the plot. Such things can be common in societies with large levels of systematic corruption and in that case, by reporting the plot, you'd only exile yourself from academia. It could quite easily happen that in such case you may need to leave your country and start looking for work elsewhere.

Now, I'm not saying that you shouldn't be rocking the boat, I'm just trying to focus a little bit on the consequences part of the question. Make sure that you have a plan in place in case your attempt to expose the plot fails.

Many people recommended that you speak to a lawyer. Instead, I'll say: Try to find a good lawyer that specializes in corruption cases and can explain to you how exactly is it realistic for you to expose people and where you should report the fraud if it is in fact feasible to report it. Then find another lawyer with same qualifications and speak to him as well! Keep in mind that in busting your adviser, you'll be making a whole bunch of enemies, many of them of high rank, quite possibly for life. People say: "The wheels of justice turn slowly, but grind exceedingly fine." Even in the case that the rest of your society is not as corrupt as I fear it to be, what are you going to do while the case is being processed, which can easily take many years? Would you be able to eat and drink your honesty?

So once again, before you actually do anything, make sure you have plans in place so you are safe if it all backfires.

Comment: I like this answer because let's face it: the supervising governmental organization obviously isn't looking too closely at what's going on if this is as easy to suss out as you seem to state.  That doesn't mean you don't have some ethical obligations here, but I dunno. I've seen a few of these deals where it's like "It would be nice but in reality..." and so everyone settles for less and maybe there are some facts here that you don't have access to.  But yeah, once you agreed to falsify the documents -- professorial encouragement or no -- you became involved just as much as anyone else.

Comment: (And before anyone jumps down my throat for saying that, just take a look at the state of government procurement in the US.  These kinds of things are happening at *all* levels and if you think academia is immune I've got some beachfront property in western Pennsylvania I'd like you to take a look at.  I'm not saying I support or condone this kind of thing, but it happens.  A lot.)

Comment: @DaveKaye: Would that be in Erie county?

Comment: I like this answer because it sheds some light on an important aspect, i.e., the country that OP is doing their research. I can think of many countries that are popular destination for PhD students and aforementioned case could result in completely different verdict in each of these countries.

Comment: In this kind of cases, the best way is to use politics against it. Chances are that, along the chain, there are strata of friends and foes that can help you. I have seen this play out at university level, not at justice level, though.

Answer (score 65):

**Warning**: Harsh answer following

Let me state some facts:

- You probably took a PhD you did not deserve ("worthless" was your original wording) to satisfy the grant requirements
- You were paid unusually lots of money for a PhD student, probably without having to do TAs but working exclusively on the grant aka your research
  (those type of grants offer very high paychecks even for the PhD students, since they also have money for relocation, living expenses etc...). In EU, PhD students on such projects are paid as much as €2700 - €3500 per month for as much as 3 years => you probably were paid >€100k.
- You probably had a very big travel budget for conferences, with little administrative overhead (contrary to most PhD students who are on a very tight travel budget)
- You put your signature on falsified documents, probably lied in person to your grant reviews, did not resign or returned the money you falsely took when you discovered the fraud.
- Having received all that money and getting your PhD, you now have a guilty conscience and a change of heart.
- You want to do the "ethical" thing but without voluntarily returning all the money you received from the grant.

Somehow, I cannot see you as a victim here.

As far as I am concerned, consulting a lawyer and voluntarily returning all the money you illegally received from the grant (after consulting your lawyer) are the only viable solutions if you want to come clean.

Comment: Even though I agree with your point, that doesn't answer the question. There is a proper approach to this.

Comment: Based on some of the comments on the question that suggest the unanswerable part of the question is the "Should I" perspective, while the answerable part of the question is the "Am I ethically obliged" perspective, I would argue this answer does a good job at laying down most (all?) of the known facts in a concise way sufficient to answer the answerable part of the question.

Comment: I agree with @O.R.Mapper that this answer lays a ground for the true answer. If you want to bust your advisor, you will need to bust yourself, too. It is very harsh as the warning says. To the OP, you were an adult when you signed up the PhD, right? Or, you were under 18 years age when you start PhD?

Comment: @yo' First of all, as a legal expert you should know that lawyers do not decide on legality but courts do. Second, if he was paid money for living abroad and he only stayed in his home country the OP committed the same fraud as anyone else did. In fact, his advisor might not even committed fraud, since a) he only supervised the students and b) he did not receive any money directly (his institution did) from the grant. So, it is mostly the administrative department that is in hot water and then the advisor responsible for the scientific part, which was done anyway.

Comment: The victim is obviously the taxpayer, as usual.

Comment: Another part that might determine OP 'role' in the fraud is "Of course I had no idea that the grant money is being mishandled until a monitoring meeting with the grant authorities that took place a long time after I started" .  Depending on what a long time is, as in, 3 months before defending PHD as a warp up to some funding, it could change responsibility

Comment: @user1938107 For EU research (3 years) programmes that fund PHD candidates, reviews happen typically every year. Also, the PHD student signs an individual contract that states the terms. Moreover, a  Google search on the grant, would clearly show the terms and conditions for eligibility. Playing damn as a PHD holder would not convince anyone.

Comment: @Alexandros I guess your last sentence would be a pretty damning statement in court.

Comment: @user1938107 Up to the point where the OP agreed to lie in the review meeting, ignorance was a defence ("They paid me a stipend to be a PhD student; I studied towards a PhD; nobody told me there were a bunch of conditions on the money"). After they lied to the review meeting, they were complicit in the fraud. It would require an unusual amount of curiosity for a PhD student to look up the terms under which the university had been awarded the grant. But everybody knows that lying is wrong.

Comment: @Alexandros: Are you aware that your answer basically amounts to "no, you should absolutely keep quiet because you'll be screwed if you speak up?" Your closing sentence suggests that you think you said something else.

Comment: @PhasmaFelis No, my answer is: You took a tons of undeserving money for delivering meaningful research due to your advisor's fraud but you delivered mediocre-to-bad results and got a probably undeserving PhD. So, stop playing the victim and blaming others for your shortcomings.

Answer (score 27):

From an **ethical** point of view, the best thing to do is to report the fraudulent behavior. As to the question of whether "[you] should support [your] supervisors back" the answer is no. There is no ethical obligation for you to keep fraudulent behavior secret to protect your previous bosses. In general the ethical code in academia differs from the one in organized crime (with some exceptions).

It sounds like you think revealing what you know might result in the obliteration of an entire department and several (*a priori* honest) people loosing their job. This is not going to make you popular among these people. But it's not a sufficient reason, again strictly ethically speaking, not to report it. They use ill-acquired money, either knowingly or not, and this money should go to someone else.

From **your** point of view,  the situation is risky of course and it's a bit late to report it, the ideal moment would have been when you were first asked to falsify reports of your expenses and actual location. If you decide to report, **seek professional legal support**.

But don't be too optimistic about the results of any investigation that might follow. In the majority of countries, it's very rare that anything is being done about people embezzling public money in academic or other government environments. If anything, the private companies involved might retract to prevent further damage.

Answer (score 27):

I have a few concerns with your post:

> it is required for some people to exchange between these places for extended periods of time. Relocate to a different place, live and work there.

How many **exactly** is "some"?

> However almost none of them actually did any exchange. Instead everyone just stayed at their home institutions.

Wait, "almost none" implies that it was *not everyone* that stayed at their institutions. That is, *some people did make the exchange.*

The point being: could it be possible that, at least at this point in what you've told us, the PI has fulfilled the obligations to the grant?

Now, though, here's a critical point:

> We ended up making ridiculous statements about our accommodation, work hours, health insurance as the senior professors convinced us to lie about fictitious exchanges taking place.

When you write "ridiculous" you mean all of those statements were *total lies*, on the part of *every* student? And that multiple professors convinced every student to blatantly lie about key features of their contracts? And no one has balked or come forward about it publicly?

Doesn't that strike you as hard to believe?

My other concern is this:

> The government thinks it's a research project with cooperation among multiple institutions. The only time we see each other is at set-up (pretended) conferences.

But in my experience, cooperation among multiple institutions often does not entail physically transplanting researchers. Are you **sure** you understand the exact requirements of the grant? That having a few key researchers exchange and occasionally meeting at conferences (what do you mean by "pretended"? Do they meet or do they not?) doesn't fulfill the grant?

**My overall point is:** you had better be perfectly sure you know exactly what is permitted under the grant and what is not before you start accusing anyone of misdeeds.

Comment: The concerns you have are very reasonable. But in total the number of fictional exchanges would add up to over a decade of claimed exchange time. Transplanting researchers is unfortunately the main point of this grant. I guess this somehow explains how the whole thing gets by unnoticed. No one expects researchers to move around, or make total lies about their whereabouts.

Comment: @rantingPhDstudent There is an answer that does not seem to have been provided yet, that while is kind of a cop out, at least gets you started on a better path and would be viewed as a normal first step in situations like this. Most Universities have Internal or Research Review committees that are likely run as an adjunct to the Provost's office or the office of the President. Approach them. It keeps everything within the institution and allows people with the authority to obtain the facts to determine what has gone on and what the course of action should be. Even if this grant...

Comment: ... is a substantial sum of money, it is likely pocket change to the money that could be lost by the entire institution should they be sanctioned from applying for any grants. They will investigate and they will make the decision that is in the best interest of the institution. It is possible that they will find that while the spirit of the grant may have not been met, the contractual obligations have been met. In that case it goes no further. If not, then not opening disciplinary reviews and reports jeopardizes there existence as a research institution, and they will likely report...

Comment: to the agency funding the grant.

Comment: Counterpoint to the "maybe it was actually okay" aspect of the above, though, is this from the question: *"...as the senior professors convinced us to lie about fictitious exchanges taking place..."* If it was okay, senior professors wouldn't be convincing PhD students to lie.

Comment: @AMR That's a really important point that I feel should probably be an answer: if you can keep it in the institution, go through the Correct Channels, etc, then you are far less likely to end up with the problems that AnrejaKo outlines, AND it becomes "someone else's problem" - you've done your bit, you've reported it, and it's the institution's problem to straighten itself out.

Comment: @DewiMorgan. Thank you. As it is a protected question, I am locked out, though I would have provided it as answer had I not been. I am not saying that it is ideal, as we saw what happened with Penn State when going through proper channels led to a massive coverup and more victims, but in this case it is probably the way to go. In any organization, junior members only get to see so much and what you think is the reality may only be bits of the truth. It doesn't sound good, but it isn't the OPs responsibility to get to the bottom of the issue either, just to raise it for internal review.

Answer (score 21):

You do not say what country you are from. Different countries have different legal systems. They also have different penalties.

If you were British or living in Britain, I'd suggest you start with the Citizens Advice Bureau. I'm pretty sure they do not ask for your full details. You could even give a false name. These organisations have contacts in all sorts of areas with experts who volunteer their specialist knowledge.

Contact any sources of help that are ***impartial*** and that will not be obliged to take action. Ask them beforehand what their policy is about reporting wrongdoing that they are told about. You can telephone a different branch from the one you intend to consult.

Think ten times or more  before you go anywhere near a body that does investigations and doles out punishments. Committees within educational establishments are not impartial. They will act in the best interests of themselves and the good name of the institution.  A few dead bodies of PhD scapegoats probably won't concern them as much as loss of a professor although it does happen.

Search your own conscience. If it's clear then go ahead. If it's not then pragmatism comes into play. Are you tough enough to take the consequences of your own actions? Can you make amends? Would that be a mitigating factor?

Finally be aware that whistle-blowing, even when done with the best will in the world and with a clear conscience can come back to bite you.

If you are outside Britain then I don't know what is available.

Good luck.

Comment: great advise. deserves more ups.

Comment: I think that you are right in saying that a university committee will look out for the best interests of the institution, but you have the wrong perspective on how they might approach this. If this whole question isn't blown out of proportion then it severely calls into question the University's ability for oversight, which depending on the jurisdiction could mean that the entire University gets sanctioned and that could be a huge sum of money if it affects there ability to obtain future grants because of questionable oversight in this situation.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers already adequately point out your moral/ethical obligation to report this (from the sound of it quite large) fraud.

I just want to add that if you *don't* report this, and assuming you want to continue in Academia, it will probably hang over you for the rest of your career. You will be afraid of being busted for this for the rest of your life, and if you are, the consequences are likely to be far more severe than they would be now. This may be your last chance to come clean and make a fresh start.

Comment: Not so quite, especially if they don't plan to continue in Academia. The thesis has been published and it itself is _not_ a false thesis, it only has questionable quality. And after some years (5 or 10 in most countries), financial frauds are statute-barred and you can't be persecuted in any way. Of  course, this does not solve the ethical/moral part of the problem.

Comment: @yo' Good point (I'll add it to my answer), although if they do continue in academia I don't think it will so easily go away. They may not be legally liable for anything, but depending on the specifics their academic reputation could still be ruined. Of course the OP him/herself knows best how likely that is...

Comment: Frankly, if they wrote a questionable-quality thesis, their chances in academia are very limited anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, but I know enough to say that this matter is not Criminal or Civil, it is Contractual. In Contractual law, individuals who are involved in a breech of contract MAY be required to pay a fine, but only in very very rare circumstances. Typically it is the company, university or institution - the one that INITIATED the contract - that has to foot the payout. I'll repeat, because there are a few sensationalist posts above mine that seem to suggest otherwise - it is not criminal to breach a contract. When the contract is initiated on behalf a registered organisation/university, it is not even Civil. Extracting money for saying you will do X and instead you do Y is NOT a criminal offence unless common law is broken or significant harm to person or persons was brought about by deliberately (and with full knowledge of the consequences) breeching the contract. This is really only ever used when safety companies fail to provide due diligence to turn a quick profit and people die.

So any legal issues with the contract will be brought to your employer, not you personally. Your employer may then wish to seek damages against you for some of their costs because you did not report it to them sooner, but such a case is certain to fail. For one, even if they win, you probably have no money to pay them and can file for bankruptcy instantly. If they lose, they will have substantial court costs to pay. What probability do they have of winning? Slim to none. You can offer both ignorance AND/OR duress as credible defences. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duress_in_English_law

So to answer your question, you should report it, and you should get a lawyer. Based on the information you have provided, you are not legally vulnerable. You are however extremely vulnerable academically. The university may revoke your PhD, and worse they might discredit your work, and make it very difficult for you to work in Science elsewhere. They do not need to provide any legal basis for doing either of these things, since PhDs are 'awarded' rather than earned. However, game theory would suggest that such a Pyrrhic victory is unlikely to be performed by a university of supposedly smart people. The effort spend in revoking your PhD is a no-win situation. But it really depends on the university when all is said and done.

Also, the only thing more impressive than a PhD is turning one down because the system failed you. Then go get a job at the grant-awarding body.

EDIT:
Due to "popular demand", and the fact that this post sits at a healthy -4, I am adding this edit.
In the above text I mention that I am not a lawyer. It goes without saying therefore that what i present isn't to be considered legal council. It is just an internet comment. However, it does contain actual legal information, which other commenters deemed incorrect, despite they themselves being frighteningly unclear on, if this went to trial, who would actually be suing whom.
They also request that I make it quite clear when I state "/Duress_in_English_Law", that I only refer to English law, because this was perhaps unclear.
In my defence, Common Law, which was developed in England and spread to the rest of the English-speaking world is actually rather... Common. Unsurprisingly, that is both why it is called Common Law, and why I referenced it in the first place. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_legal_systems#Common_law

One of the nice things about Common Law is that many things, like the definition of basic legal terms such as "fraud", are very very similar wherever Common Law is applied. This is what makes having a conversation about law over the internet possible, without having to constantly qualify everything.

So I think it's fair to say that everything in this post is probably relevant to the OP, and isn't just some wishy-washy "do it because it's the right thing" or "if you don't do it you'll burn in hell" vote bait. I dont care for votes. What matters is that this guy DOES go to a lawyer, and DOES bring this matter to the attention of the grant-funding body. The chances of that happening is so very very much higher if he appreciates that he is not personally liable, as all the above nonesense brolawyer posts above suggest.

Comment: This depends on the jurisdiction, that the OP has not revealed. Also, I doubt institutions anywhere can revoke PhD degrees without, at least, a good explanation. They are official titles registered with the government of the country.

Comment: "He lied about compulsory meetings" is as good a reason as any. There is no accountability or legal trouble whatsoever to revoke a PhD - the courts always defer to the University's judgement. Case in point, I took my Uni to court because my Bachelor thesis was marked by two people: one gave me 20% the other 80%. The university averaged to 50%. No 3rd marker. I made a case that this was poor statistics at best. The judge favoured the Uni, saying however they calculate marks it must be OK. It took 2 years before i got into med school. The guy who gave me 20% later published my work as his own.

Comment: Fraud is both a civil wrong and a criminal wrong in most jurisdictions. You cannot say "oh it's merely a contractual breach so it cannot also be a criminal matter"—that isn't true.

Comment: Had to downvote this due to blanket statements such as "it is not criminal to breach a contract". [There are countries where at least some forms of breaching a contract seem to be considered a criminal offence.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eingehungsbetrug) And even without that, I doubt the statement "not Criminal or Civil, it is Contractual" makes sense for all countries - depending on the legislation, in case of a contractual disagreement, a civil lawsuit is the way to go.

Comment: This is dangerously wrong, in a number of ways. For one, "contractual" is a matter of civil law in many countries, such as the US. For another, knowingly and intentionally misrepresenting for purposes of gain when it causes material damage to another is generally criminal fraud (just for starters). Whether or not it is chosen to be prosecuted becomes a different question. In the US, for example, criminal fraud may even be a felony depending on the amount of damage. Do not rely on random statements like this answer where local law may differ or which may be entirely wrong: consult a lawyer.

Comment: @Calchas It isn't fraud. It is breach of contract. The requirements for fraud are not met for very much the same reasons that walking into a crime scene and not going straight to the cops is not murder. I cannot speak for the University, but regarding the question "what consequences could it have for me?", fraud is not on the table. Of course I do not know exactly how it would go down, but I suspect the University would EITHER be sued for breach of contract, OR be sued for fraud in the inducement, both of which protect the OP of fraud charges.

Comment: @taswyn and O.R. Mapper:
Your quite right, law does differ by country. My answer, which specifically mentions in the text British law, suggests this. I also gave an example of where being found guilty of Contractual law can lead to criminal or civil damages. I'm just amazed at these replies - it's like you both only read the first line and stopped reading immediately to comment...

Comment: "We ended up making ridiculous statements about our accommodation, work hours, health insurance as the senior professors convinced us to lie about fictitious exchanges taking place." To me that looks like making a false representation with intention of procuring gain. In England&Wales that satisfies s(2) of the Fraud Act 2006. My alternative charge as a prosecutor would be accessory to fraud from the date he received a pay cheque after learning about it. Alternatively it could be false accounting under the Theft Act.

Comment: The grant existed before the OP joined the university. For this to be fraud and not, what it really is, the violation of some collateral clauses in the contract regarding meetings and communication, the contract would have had to have been initiated with this intentionally in mind (by the Uni). Since the OP did not know anything was even amiss until AFTER he was well into his sub-contract with the university (unless he is on a stipend in which case there really is no legal link at all), there is no possible way that this is fraud. For a bunch of academics you really need to go back to school..

Comment: There is no fraud in contract law. The existence of fraud nullifies any contract. So either we accept that the STUDENT committed fraud, and its entirely a civil/criminal fraud case, or we accept that the STUDENT did not commit fraud, and this is entirely a contractual issue that the student did not perform their duties to the university by informing them of their own legal vulnerability. We differ on this. I dont think any more comments will resolve it either... :P

Comment: There is a big step between assessing if the grading is fair and revoking a title. The first is done according to university regulations, and they have some leeway to set them; the second has some requirement set by law.

Comment: It may not be fraud to breach a contract, but it is definitely fraud to lie about what you did and then obtain other government money later on based on these lies. Also, you can be sued for breaching the contract. Given the extent of the deception it is highly likely they would win the lawsuit and collect a large amount of money. Also, whichever university is employing the liar would likely take disciplinary action based on the lies (i.e. fire him). So while it's technically not fraud to lie, he will still be in serious trouble if it gets exposed.

Comment: "My answer, which specifically mentions in the text British law, suggests this." - No, it does not. It does contain a WP link related to British law, but nothing in your text says that is anything else than a limited example. Your whole text seems tos ay "world-wide, a breach of contract is not criminal or civil offence". Furthermore, I did *not* only read the first line, which is how I was able to reply to the fifth line. I suggest you thoroughly rewrite your answer in a way that clarifies you are specifically talking about the hypothetical (and possible) case British law is relevant here.

Comment: I applaud this alternative view. They state OP should get a lawyer then the very rationally explain why they don't think the OP is not going to be crucified. A big public trial and junior staff fried will cast a long shadow that all the grants they awarded were embezzled. They will want to shut it down as quietly as possible out of court. Supervisors will be exited and the uni will settle out of court. If OP gets crucified and gets a sympathetic write up in a newspaper it's a PR melt down for uni and grant body. If they shoot the OP they risk the ricochet hitting themselves between the eyes.

Comment: ... the actual ultimate wronged party is the tax payer as their money was misappropriated. All other parties all have a vested interest in sweeping the affair under the carpet. They will want the OP to keep out of the limelight so will rattle the sword to encourage silence after the affair. Still this is all an observation of what a rational party will do and they might not act rationally. So get a lawyer.

Comment: @user3329564 - Comments are ephemeral and not intended for long discussion. This policy varies from site to site, see [this meta question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/805/is-deleting-comments-a-form-of-censorship) for more detail.

Comment: @user3329564 How, exactly, have you come to the conclusion that it wouldn't be fraud unless he lied before the beginning of the grant? The UK Fraud Act doesn't say anything of the sort. You are trying to say "if this falls under area of law X it cannot fall under area of law Y;" that is not actually how things work. Lying during a grant review in order to keep the grant can be both a civil breach of contract *and* a criminal fraud (and contract law is handled in civil cases in the UK, incidentally). The relevant case would be the Crown bringing a case against an individual.

Comment: @Davidmh (1st comment) as far as I know, in the US at least the government has no involvement with PhDs. They carry no official weight, are not registered with anybody except the granting institution, and revocation is entirely subject to that institution's rules.

Comment: The simple fact is that lying to government investigators (of any sort) is a crime in virtually every country and jurisdiction on earth.  Otherwise, individuals would not feel compelled to tell investigators the truth and there would be little point to their jobs and little reason for the government to even have investigations of any sort.

Comment: Yes. One day your signing bits of paper your boss hands you without fully appreciating what you are doing or why you're doing it, the next, total anarchy as government spins out of control and civilisation becomes just a  meaningless concept.

Comment: Not at all what I said.  But thanks for that strawman analysis...